# How do I put a panel of buttons into flow layout panel?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I have a panel of labels, buttons and image that I wish to put into a flow layout panel.

As seen in some tutorial, I understand that it is possible to auto align new and additional buttons into a flow layout panel.

what I would like to ask is that is it possible to put a panel WITHIN a flow layout panel and call multiple instances of the same panel to appear within the flow layout panel.

My panel code would be

```
        this.panelNotification.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.lblImage);
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.lblName);
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.lblLinkName);
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.lblLinkLocation);
        this.panelNotification.Controls.Add(this.lblLocation);
        this.panelNotification.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.panelNotification.Name = "panelNotification";
        this.panelNotification.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(506, 100);
        this.panelNotification.TabIndex = 17;
```

So is it possible to include the whole panel into a flow layout panel? if yes, how do i do it. thank you.

Comment: side note: you should accept answers to your questings that helped you since some people won't answer your questions if you don't accept answers.

Comment: oh sorry. still pretty new to this stackoverflow thingy. will take note of that! thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can put a Panel into a FlowLayoutoutPanel.
No, you can't put a control several times into a FlowLayoutoutPanel (in fact you can, but it is only displayed once).

But what you could do is writing some kind of Factory-Method that creates a new Panel with new Buttons/Labels/other Controls etc. every time you call it, and add these new instances to your FlowLayoutpanel. Something like this:

```
public class Form1
{
    private Panel CreateNotificationPanel()
    {
        var p = new Panel { BackColor = Color.Red };
        p.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Test" });
        return p;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var flp = new FlowLayoutPanel { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };

        flp.Controls.Add(CreateNotificationPanel());
        flp.Controls.Add(CreateNotificationPanel());
        flp.Controls.Add(CreateNotificationPanel());

        this.Controls.Add(flp);
    }

    public Form1() { Load += Form1_Load; }
}
```

Another (and problably better) approach would be to create a UserControl that contains your Buttons/Labels/etc. instead of using a panel and adding all controls manually. Just create with the Designer and add new instances of the UserControl to the FlowLayoutPanel.

Comment: oh. so how am I suppose to write a method that creates a new panel with all those buttons inside? do I code it in the main.cs file? could you show me a small sample of it? thanks!

Comment: hi thanks for the codes. for the createNotificationPanel method, how do i specify where the buttons go to? and how do i specify the points where the flp appears? thanks!

Comment: You could, instead of using a method that creates a Panel, create a UserControl with the designer. Would be the easiest approach.

Comment: i'm sorry but i am still relatively new to c# programming using visual studio. may I know what do you mean by that? would it be a hassle for me to just create a instance of panel with the buttons and locations specified by me in main.cs?

Comment: If you have no problem with creating the Panel by code, then go for it. But creating a UserControl would be easier IMHO, since you can create it with the designer.

Comment: okay. what i would like to ask is if i want to create the panel by code. what is the code that is used to specify the drawing location of the panel in my form?

Comment: If you want to specify an absolute position, use the Location-Property of the Panel to set the position